# Kernel Panic , after i added helloworld sys call

Tags: linux-kernel, system-calls

Crash Picture:
[image: Crash]

https://youtu.be/85qGRoaOkhQ   Followed every step from this video

im using 20.04.1-Ubuntu
linux kernel currently using 5.15.0-67
updating to linux-5.15.94

Downloaded linux 5.15.94 from kernel.org

made helloworld folder in it, inside
made 2 files, helloworld.c and Makefile

code inside Helloworld.c

```
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/syscalls.h>
SYSCALL_DEFINE0(helloworld)   // this line has been placed the one with screenshot
{
    printk("Hello world\n");
    return 0;
}
```

inside make file:    `obj-y := helloworld.o`

inside syscalls_64.tbl
added line 499

```
499 common helloworld sys_helloworld
```

Location: arch/x86/entry/syscalls_64.tbl

declared func in syscalls.h
Location: include/linux

```
 asmlinkage long sys_helloworld(void);
```

edited .config file
in which

```
config_x86_x32 = n from y
```

Ran these two commands in terminal as they were interfering while compiling "make -j8"
scripts/config --disable SYSTEM_REVOCATION_KEYS
scripts/config --disable SYSTEM_TRUSTED_KEYS

compiled and install with make -j8 and make module_install install , after this update-grub

all done now, when i reboot i my virtual machine crash, it does show kernel version i added so i know all steps are done perfectly, also i can access old version im using.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that your **new kernel** works **without** adding a syscall? And your screenshot doesn't contain the initial error message: it starts from the middle of the stack trace, but the error message is somewhere above. Debugging without the error message has a little sense.

Comment: no new kernel does not work at all